# Comparator vs Closure in min call in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I am trying to understand the difference between passing a `Closure` vs a `Comparator` to the `min` function on a collection:

```
// Example 1: Closure/field/attribute?
Sample min = container.min { it.timespan.start }

// Example 2: Comparator
Sample min2 = container.min(new Comparator<Sample>() {
  @Override
  int compare(Sample o1, Sample o2) {
    return o1.timespan.start <=> o2.timespan.start
  }
})
```

They both return the correct result.

Where:

```
class Sample {
    TimeSpan timespan
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

And:

```
class TimeSpan {
  LocalDate start
  LocalDate end
}
```

In **Example 1** I just pass the field `timespan.start` to `min` which I guess means that I am passing a `Closure` (even though its just a field in a class)?

In **Example 1** does groovy convert the field `timespan.start` into a `Comparator` behind the scenes like the one I create explicitly in **Example 2**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is, that those are two different `min` methods both
taking different arguments.  There is one for passing
a [closure](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#min(T%5B%5D,groovy.lang.Closure))
and one for the
[comparator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#min(T%5B%5D,java.util.Comparator))
(there is a third one using identity and some deprecated ones, but we can ignore that for now).

The first version (`Closure` with one (implicit argument)) you have to
extract the value from the passed value, you want to make the `min`
aggregate with.  Therefor this versions has some inner working to deal
with comparing the values.

But the docs also state:

> If the closure has two parameters it is used like a traditional
> Comparator. I.e. it should compare its two parameters for order,
> returning a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer when the
> first parameter is less than, equal to, or greater than the second
> respectively. Otherwise, the Closure is assumed to take a single
> parameter and return a Comparable (typically an Integer) which is then
> used for further comparison.

So you can use a Closure version also to the same as your second example
(you have to define two params explicitly):

```
container.min{ a, b -> a <=> b }
```

And there is also a shorter version of the second example.  You can cast
a Closure to an interface with groovy.  So this works too:

```
container.min({ a, b -> a <=> b } as Comparator)
```